# Using map<pair<int,int>,string> in C++

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ map. I want to use a map something like the following in my program.

```
std::map<std::pair<int,int>,string> pattern
```

Here the key `int,int` actually row position and column position of a two dimensional grid and column is unknown initially. So I have thought to set the column initially to value 0. In course of the program, it may be negative also. So could anyone help me how to access and set elements of such map?

Comment: Did you mean `std::map<std::pair<int,int>,string> pattern`?

Comment: What is you problem exactly? The documentation of `map` class is quite clear and concise with regard to setting/retrieving elements. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map

Comment: did you try using `std::map<std::pair<int,int>,string>::iterator`?

Comment: use `std::make_pair` to make the pair.  Or you can use brace initialization.  `pattern.get({1, 2});` or `pattern.get(make_pair(1, 2))`  If that's what your question is.

Comment: Thanks, I have not used pair before.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity There is no `map::get` function. There is `at`, which may be called as you described, and `operator[]`, which works with `pattern[{1,2}]`.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not entirely clear.  But this small sample demonstrates how to initialize the map whose key consists of a row column pair (10 rows and 10 columns in the example), and the value of each key is of the pattern "row, column".  Then the sample iterates the maps and prints out each key value pair of the map.

```
map<pair<int,int>,string> patterns;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        patterns[make_pair(i, j)] = std::to_string (i) + ", " + std::to_string (j);   
    }
}

for (const auto &pair : patterns) {
    std::cout << pair.first.first << "," << pair.first.second << ": " << pair.second << '\n';
    //note pair.first in the row column pair, pair.first.first is the row, pair.first.second is the column, pair.second is the string pattern
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as you compile in C++11 mode (which, as of 2014, you should), the value of the pair may be specified as a *braced-init-list*, e.g. `{ 4, -13 }`, in most interface functions of `map`. This does not work with `emplace` or anything else using perfect forwarding.

For example:

```
patterns[{ 1, 2 }] = "hello"; // set a given element
patterns.at[{ 1, 2 }] = "Hello"; // alter a given pre-existing element
foo( patterns.at[{ 1, 2 }] ); // pass a (reference to) pre-existing element
patterns.erase({ 3 , 4 }); // ensure that given element no longer exists
```